# Specifying new option for hop by hop extension header IPv6?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ipv6, raw-sockets

I have been trying to get an answer for this for sometime now but not been able to find it.

Is there a way that I can specify a new option value for the hop by hop extension header in IPv6, so that I can parse the value in the user space rather than the kernel parsing it?

The kernel when tries to parse the value, sends me an ICMP reply stating parameter not recognized for that value in the header.

I'm wondering if there should be a way to deploy and test new options in IPv6 extension header without writing handlers for them as LKM.

There isn't a lot available on the web for IPv6, so any help from IPv6 experts would be great!

RFC 2460 mentions this. I assume you can create a new option type for testing any new applications:

> Mindful of the need for compatibility with existing IPv6 deployments,
>   new IPv6 extension headers MUST NOT be created or specified, unless
>   no existing IPv6 Extension Header can be used by specifying a new
>   option for that existing IPv6 Extension Header.  Any proposal to
>   create or specify a new IPv6 Extension Header MUST include a detailed
>   technical explanation of why no existing IPv6 Extension Header can be
>   used in the Internet-Draft proposing the new IPv6 Extension Header.

Answer (score 0):

As for "The kernel when tries to parse the value, sends me an ICMP reply ..." you mentioned,  by "kernel" I assume you means a remote ipv6 node ( either router or destination host ).    Then you might set the "Option Type" wrong way in your egress packet sending by raw-socket.

As RFC 2460 says:

The Option Type identifiers are internally encoded such that their highest-order two bits specify the action that must be taken if the processing IPv6 node does not recognize the Option Type:

00,  01,  10,  11  ....

--- I guess you fill in "10" or "11",  you could fill in "00"

Comment: putting a value of "00" in Option Type field will result in the kernel  skipping over this header. (which is not the case I want).I want to be able to edit the edit ad/or display the values from this option header.

Comment: "00" makes any intermediate routers and destination host not drop this packet in kernel-level stack.  And then, could use raw socket to receive & send the packet data, along with it Hop extension header.    See <<RFC 3542 - Advanced Sockets Application Program Interface (API) for IPv6>>   8.1.  Receiving Hop-by-Hop Options  &  8.2.  Sending Hop-by-Hop Options.      I myself not tried, but should able to work.